# How to filter and sort stream of large text file in Python

Tags: python, time-series, bigdata

I have a large text file (>1GB) of three comma-separated values that I want to read into a Pandas DataFrame in chunks.  An example of the DataFrame is below:

[image: output]

I'd like to filter through this file while reading it in and output a "clean" version.  One issue I have is that some Timestamps are out-of-order, but the problem is usually quite local (usually a tick is out-of-order by a few slots before or below).  Are there any ways to do localized, "sliding window" sorting?

Also, as I'm fairly new to Python, and learning about the I/O methods, I'm unsure of the best class/method to use for filtering large data files.  TextIOBase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really interesting question, as the data's big enough to not fit in memory easily.

First of all, about I/O: if it's a CSV I'd use a standard library [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object, like so (I'm assuming Python 3):

```
with open('big.csv', newline='') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ...
```

Then I'd probably keep a sliding window of rows in a [`collections.deque(maxlen=WINDOW_SIZE)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instance with window size set to maybe 20 based on your description. Read the first `WINDOW_SIZE` rows into the deque, then enter the main read loop which would output the left-most item (row) in the deque, then append the current row.

After appending each row, if the current row's timestamp comes before the timestamp of the previous rows (`window[-2]`), then sort the deque. You can't sort a deque directly, but do something like:

```
window = collections.deque(sorted(window), maxlen=WINDOW_SIZE)
```

Python's Timsort algorithm handles already-sorted runs efficiently, so this should be very fast (linear time).

If the window size and the number of out-of-order rows are small (as it sounds like they can be), I believe the overall algorithm will be O(N) where N is the number of rows in the data file, so linear time.

UPDATE: I wrote some demo code to generate a file like this and then sort it using the above technique -- see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/benhoyt/fae1d584435a5dcff65c8330fe368a78), tested on Python 3.5. It's much faster than the `sort` utility on the same data, and also faster than Python's `sorted()` function after about N = 1,000,000. Incidentally the function that generates a demo CSV is significantly slower than the sorting code. :-) My results timing  `process_sliding()` for various N (definitely looks linear-ish):

- N = 1,000,000: 3.5s
- N = 2,000,000: 6.6s
- N = 10,000,000: 32.9s

For reference, here's the code for my version of `process_sliding()`:

```
def process_sliding(in_filename, out_filename, window_size=20):
    with (open(in_filename, newline='') as fin,
          open(out_filename, 'w', newline='') as fout):
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        writer = csv.writer(fout)

        first_window = sorted(next(reader) for _ in range(window_size))
        window = collections.deque(first_window, maxlen=window_size)

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(window.popleft())
            window.append(row)
            if row[0] < window[-2][0]:
                window = collections.deque(sorted(window), maxlen=window_size)

        for row in window:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I would use iteetools.islice to get a chuck of data

Comment: @Copperfield Can you be more specific? If you mean when fetching that `first_window` chunk, I thought about that, but I think it's often clearer and simpler to avoid imports and use more basic builtins.

Comment: yes, I mean on `first_window`. Also your current way have the risk of throwing an StopIteration exception, maybe for this use case that is not a problem, but why leave a easily avoidable problem there?